# Omitting "to be" in present continuous

Tags: present-continuous

Sometimes I come across sentences or phrases which should (in my opinion) contain the verb "to be" (present continuous tense) but they actually don't.
Last time I saw that on CNN in the running line, there was something like "Trump and Clinton working to flip states in their favor" (it was not a capitalized title).

So, is there any rule for that or it's just a feature of mass media?

UPD: here's the answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese

Comment: Newspapers  and news media  in general tend to short the  titles for reason  of space.

Comment: Titles, subtitles, and picture captions (for example) do not have to be full sentences.  But this would not be done in the body of an article.  Omitting the verb "to be" will make any sentence sound like the title of something.

Comment: I thought it's applicable only for capitalized titles. Ok, thanks, I'll keep in mind that news media use their own rules :)

Comment: If you look up "Headlinese", you'll find plenty of information about this style.

Comment: Remember, though: it is not just journalists who use their own "rules", but almost everyone who speaks English. Those "rules" are not mandatory. There is no enforcement body that punishes violators. Even outside of journalism, writers and speakers write and speak English just as they wish. The grammarians come after, making "rules" out of those usages. The usages come first, and the rules are merely their result; so don't be surprised or puzzled when you find something that doesn't follow those "rules" you've learned. Most English speakers never give them a thought.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure there's no some tricky rule which I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Update: here's the answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese

Newspapers and news media in general tend to short the titles for reason of space.

Remember, though: it is not just journalists who use their own "rules", but almost everyone who speaks English. Those "rules" are not mandatory. There is no enforcement body that punishes violators. Even outside of journalism, writers and speakers write and speak English just as they wish. The grammarians come after, making "rules" out of those usages. The usages come first, and the rules are merely their result; so don't be surprised or puzzled when you find something that doesn't follow those "rules" you've learned. Most English speakers never give them a thought.

Comment: Re: "writers and speakers write and speak English just as they wish": This is misleading. Most writers and speakers wish to follow the rules of forms of English they're writing and speaking in; for example, no one would say "Trump and Clinton working to flip states in their favor" when speaking aloud, because that doesn't conform to the rules of spoken English, and no one has any desire to violate the rules in that way.