# There is no verb "be" in sentence

Tags: verbs

I sometimes see a line in a movie or book without the verb "be" like...

> Request accepted! Hang on.

Isn't it supposed to be...

> XRequest **is** accepted! Hang on.

or

> Rocket launched. And is inbound.

Shouldn't it be as follows?

> Rocket **is** launched. And is inbound.

Comment: No, colloquially the noun plus the past participle are used especially in things like radiocommunications, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omitting "to be" in present continuous](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108061/omitting-to-be-in-present-continuous)

Answer (score 4):

It's just abbreviated language. The kind of language in your example is very similar to military radio communication protocol, where terms like 'request acknowledged' or 'permission denied' are used for clarity and to save time.

Because this kind of militaristic language feels emotionless and detached, it has long been imagined by writers of science fiction that computers would adopt a similar abbreviated language. And in reality, many computer applications do use such language.

Comment: Very common is 'message understood!'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Roger. Over and out.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't have at least three upvotes so far. People are just plain mean. It gets so tiring.